# Getting data from vertica using Hue sqoop 2

Tags: jdbc, vertica, hue, sqoop2

I have installed CDH Hue and it is fully running , I'm trying to get data from vertica using hue sqoop2. To make a new connection sqoop hue ask me for some parameters, setting it as follow

**Name:** Vertica
**Connector:** generic-jdbc-connector
**JDBC Driver Class:** com.vertica.Driver
**JDBC Connection String:** jdbc:vertica://host001:5433/Stock_Schema
**Username:** XXXX
**Password:** XXXX

The thing is that I can't create the connection because a message "**Can't load specified driver**"  shows up. I tried to load the connector to the path **/var/lib/sqoop2** (vertica-jdbc-4.1.14.jar,vertica-jdk5-6.1.3-0.jar) also tried to set env var **$HADOOP_CLASSPATH** but anything of this works.

Can you give me any guess?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you put the jar on the Sqoop2 machine?

Does it contain the exact class?
`jar -tf vertica-jdbc-4.1.14.jar | grep  com.vertica.Driver`

You could ask on the [Sqoop list too](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!forum/cdh-user).